# Possible bug in answer ordering

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Usually ordering is on the basis of total score, with accepted answers pinned to the top unless the answer is by OP. Today on a couple of questions I have seen something else:
[Python: no module named datetime?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509283/python-no-module-named-datetime)
[image: Today I]

There was one other question, which I can't find now, where this happened. It's as if the ordering is by age.

Now I am seeing it in another question: [How do I change the hostname without a restart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart/)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those are sorted like that for me.

Check your sorting choice (the bar at the top of the answers), it looks like you have it set to oldest first. Set it to Votes and it should behave as you'd expect.

[image]

Comment: When did that option appear? I have never changed my order preference before.

Comment: @muru That option has been there since I can remember..  A long time :-)

Comment: @Seth talk about blind spots. :) But I have never noticed it, let alone changed it.. Mysteries of the universe.

Comment: It's possible that you followed a link from somebody else that had the option set. That will change your settings too (that's quite common with links to the `/questions?...` pages which work in a similar way